# chrome is opening window.open() in full window mode.

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to open a new window in chrome,my problem is that chrome is opening new window in full window mode.
here is my code:

```
myWindow=window.open('http://google.com','name','toolbar=1,scrollbars=1,location=1,statusbar=0,menubar=1,resizable=1,width=400,height=200');
```

it is working fine in mozilla.
here is my jsfiddle ex. link:[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QjLk6/).

any answer will be recieved  greatfully.

Comment: It's working as expected (not fullscreen) on my Chrome 29.0.1547.62

Comment: Your JSFIDDLE works as expected for me in Chrome. The Window opened 400x200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling and then reinstalling solved my problem..
thanks  a lot for all responses.

Comment: It's good practice to leave a comment as to why a downvote is awarded but sadly that rarely happens. Don't fret too much over it and keep on trucking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check your browser settings because I am in Chrome and the JSFiddle code worked perfectly fine for me. The browser opened with width 400 and height 200. Also, check your actual code to make sure it is the same as the one you posted.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,i will check browser setting.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. It works fine.

```
function myFunction() {
     var myWindow = window.open("http://google.com", "", 
     "width=400,height=200");
}
```